# Do resonances always correspond to on-mass-shell virtual particles in tree-level Feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I understand that the main consensus on this site is that virtual particles should not be interpreted too physically and simply correspond to terms in a perturbative expansion, so please forgive my sloppy explanation of the background to my question - my actual question is not about this background.

Like in this question ([Why do bound states increase cross sections?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318448/why-do-bound-states-increase-cross-sections)), it often seems possible to represent a given resonance state with a Feynman diagram where the resonance state is in place of a virtual particle - so one can somewhat think of it as an 'on-mass-shell virtual particle'.

[image]

My actual question is whether you get resonances when virtual particles in *non-tree-level* Feynman diagrams are on-mass-shell. Is it even possible?

For instance could you have a Feynman diagram (which contains *multiple* virtual particles) where some virtual particles are off-mass shell and others are on-mass-shell intermediate states, and would this produce a cross-section peak, or would the peak be masked by the fact that the Feynman diagram contributes less due to its increased number of nodes? Or, in other words, are all observed resonances expressable by a tree-level Feynman diagram?

In other words, if at least one propagator in the perturbative expansion diverged but not all of them, would this produce a resonance peak in a cross-section graph? Is it even possible for just a few but not all propagators to diverge?

Maybe another way of phrasing my question is, can you have situations where some of the internal legs in a complicated Feynman diagram would actually work as a valid Feynman diagram just by themselves, if some of those internal legs are 'on-mass-shell' and so would work as external legs in a Feynman diagram by themself? I understand this will involve the complexities of renormalisation of which I am not familiar so this could be a meaningless question to ask.

Comment: Just a small point: There is no hard differentiation between on and off mass-shell here. Virtual particles always have a finite lifetime and thus not a sharp energy, so you cannot have an interaction where you hit exactly the mass of the virtual particle (this is why the amplitudes are not actually divergent). And how close you are to the maximum depends on the parameters of each collision.

Comment: Also, there are interaction that do not have a tree-level contribution (such as the famous penguin diagrams), maybe those could show multiple resonances. This would mean that the amplitude $\mathcal{M}(p_1,p_2,..)$ has multiple poles in the complex plane (i.e. at complex momenta). Whenever you come close to these poles (but remain at real momenta), you get a resonance.

Comment: Yes that is a good point and I think I understand that

Comment: Wouldnt that situation be called tree-level (if you define tree level as the most significant Feynman diagrams, even if they contain more nodes than you'd usually expect)? Although it is a very interesting point, if the most significant Feynman diagrams have multiple virtual particles and therefore multiple opportunities to be on-mass-shell even for a single Feynman diagram.

Comment: Oh, yes exactly! Thats the wrong term here. I meant "where the tree-level diagram contains multiple virtual particles".

Comment: (actually Wikipedia may use your initial terminology, either way its just terminology)

Comment: What do you think about propagators diverging in non-tree-level Feynman diagrams though?

Comment: **The Z is not a resonance**, it is an elementary particle . Resonances and bound states happen between elementary particles . In feynman diagrams it is elementary particles  that are the virtual ones , have the quantum numbers of the particles but the mass off shell.