# Can we track phonon's path similarly to how we track electron's path in a bubble chamber?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, quasiparticles

An answer to a [recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423985/21441) argues that Standard Model's particles like electron are "real" because we can see their tracks in e.g. bubble chamber.

So now I wonder: can we track quasiparticles like phonons in a similar way, registering their paths in the medium where they propagate?