# About Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

What would happen if someone invented a way to measure both position and momentum precisely? If it is impossible why?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54184/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sense that the mathematical derivation of the uncertainty principle may not be a sufficient explanation... :) But if you're interested, look at the answer here: [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle scientific proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24116/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-scientific-proof?rq=1)

Think about how we look at something in macro space - we shine a light on it, such as with a microscope, and see what reflects back. In the case of a very small particle, this light could be as small as one photon - but one photon has enough momentum to push the object we're examining when they collide. So if we want to know where a particle is in space, we bounce a photon off of it - but this accelerates the particle, so now its momentum is "uncertain" (or changed). Likewise if we want to know what its momentum is - now its position has changed.

Whatever technique is used to measure a quantity (photons are just an example), it necessarily has an impact on the subject of that measurement. Thus it is impossible to measure these quantities simultaneously to a degree of precision which exceeds the uncertainty principle's limitations.

Comment: The uncertainty principle is much more than just the statement of the observer effect.

Comment: I know this question closed, however let me add a comment. If that measurement "would happen" the system would return reverse time to its past in order to "have it avoided"! It sounds crazy but so it would.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably heard the observational reason for the uncertainty principle which basically states that if you measure either position or momentum very accurately your measurement changes the other.  That's a really nice hand-wavy explanation but the uncertainty principle is fundamental to waves and is not about measurement.

Check out the [Wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).  The second paragraph states:

> [...] the uncertainty principle actually states a fundamental property of quantum systems, and is not a statement about the observational success of current technology

The article goes on to spell out in detail why this is so.