# Is there any defect in Rutherford's atomic model according to quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

According to quantum mechanics charged bodies do not emit energy continuously . Then why the [atomic model of Rutherford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_model) has the defects of collapsing nucleus, continues spectrum.

Comment: The premise of your question is just wrong. Your generalized statement of "According to quantum mechanics charged bodies do not emit energy" is also wrong. To get you started, here are some useful and simple reads: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_was_the_problem_with_Rutherford's_model_of_the_atom
http://www.sparknotes.com/testprep/books/sat2/chemistry/chapter4section4.rhtml
http://www.nuffieldfoundation.org/practical-physics/atom-%E2%80%93-quantum-mechanical-model

Comment: It has all [the failings of the Bohr model](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114341/520) plus the inability to explain the discrete atomic spectra or why the electrons don't spiral in.

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics, accelerated charged particles do emit electromagnetic waves. However, in an undisturbed atom, quantum mechanics tells us that the electrons are not behaving like particles but are more like standing waves (the so called wave function).  It is a difficult concept to grasp, but what we call particles are sometimes more like waves than particles, according to QM. The electrons in atoms have various wave-functions or probability distributions about the nucleus and do not "orbit" it.  They are not accelerating and therefore not radiating.  In Rutherford's time, these concepts had not yet been developed and people thought electrons where always particles, and in an atom they would have to be accelerating around the positive nucleus to resist from falling in.