# Why is Bohr's explanation called Bohr's model and not Bohr's theory?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, atomic-physics, models

I have seen an answer which tells the difference between model (specific) and a theory (general). And it makes sense 'coz Bohr explained it for the hydrogen atom only. 
But did he not make a set of hypotheses and test them with spectral experiments??
I know he just correlated spectral data, but still..

Comment: It's not a theory because it has very little explanatory power, and was junked less than 15 years after being proposed. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89351/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114341/. It persists as a teaching model for a number of reasons but there is a bit of a movement to do away with the emphasis that has historically but put on the developmental quantum thinking in teaching modern physics (in favor of starting with correct models from the get go).

Comment: Terminology questions, such as, e.g., _Why is the standard model not called the standard theory?_ or _Why is string theory not called the string model?_ are typically  non-constructive and primarily opinion-based, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post.

Comment: @dmckee nailed it. Models apply to specific cases which are not well understood/understanding them in terms of a deeper theory is not feasible.

Comment: @dmckee: I certainly hope that we stop teaching failed models outside of science history and start teaching the (more) correct solutions from the get-go. It's high time to equip people with 20th century physics knowledge.