# Formation of Line Spectra in light of Bohr's Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, discrete

I am reading about the electronic structure.

It is written that when hydrogen's electron comes back to ground state from excited state, it releases energy in a specific amount according to Bohr. But in Rutherford's atom, the electron continuously radiate energy and finally reaches to nucleus according to Classical Mechanics.

I have derived roughly that the reason of formation of line spectra is the "release of energy in specific amount" whereas the reason of formation of continuous spectrum is the " continuous release of energy"

Can I make these statements safely at elementary level? It's going to be asked in exams briefly so I want to be sure if these statements are correct to make at beginner level or not.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89351/    http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114341/

Answer (score 0):

> I have derived roughly that the reason of formation of line spectra is the "release of energy in specific amount" whereas the reason of formation of continuous spectrum is the " continuous release of energy" Can I make these statements safely at elementary level?

No, because there can be continuous release of energy even for source with line spectrum (laser) and there can be release of specific amount of energy with broad spectrum (short pulses of bulb light).