# Why don’t electrons radiate energy when in circular orbits?

Tags: atomic-physics

Wikipedia states that

> The electrons can only orbit stably, without radiating, in certain orbits (called by Bohr the "stationary orbits") at a certain discrete set of distances from the nucleus. These orbits are associated with definite energies and are also called energy shells or energy levels. In these orbits, the electron's acceleration does not result in radiation and energy loss as required by classical electromagnetic.

How can you just say anything? Is there any proof of this statement ? I mean, electrons are also objects and they must follow the classical theories!

PS- Please try not to use QM, as Bohr did not explain this stuff by QM!

Comment: It wasn't explained in Bohr's model: it was an *ad hoc* assumption made to give something that would agree with the data. It turned out to have modest predictive power so (despite having a few disaterous flaws) was used for a few year before being supplanted by a proper theory. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89351/why-is-the-bohrs-idea-of-defined-circular-orbits-overruled and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114341/what-is-wrong-with-the-bohr-model.

Comment: Now you sound just like Bohr, with his correspondence principle :) You can't just say, they are electrons, (objects), so they **must** follow classical theories. Why?? They are not classical objects.  Am I kidding you, a bit yes, sorry but I couldn't resist. Actually, lots of physics is based on someone saying " it must be this way", but then we have to prove it, as in the discovery of the neutrino.

Comment: Forget about that something is orbiting about nucleus. Bohrs model is wrong and would changed by areas of probability where electrons are located or dislocated.

Comment: "PS- Please try not to use QM, as Bohr did not explain this stuff by QM! " And thus you struck the problem's crux! See, that's the thing? There _was_ no explanation, it was just an ad hoc model to explain the observed quantization. QM _is_ the theory that gives you the correct explanation. QM was created both because the Bohr model was very limited _and_ because it had no explanation! The classical theory died! That was the whole point!