# Kepler's laws at atomic level

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, orbital-motion, atomic-physics, orbitals

If Coulomb's inverse square Law of forces operates between two electrostatic charges and at an atomic level as well (as in Newton's gravitational Law), has it been verified that Kepler's Laws which are their basis also hold good at that level? We are comparing the universe to elementary atomic models like for Hydrogen, Helium.

Comment: The [Bohr solar system model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) has been refuted quite thoroughly, so no, Kepler's laws don't apply to the atom.

Comment: That might not work and that's why we have Quantum Mechanics(which applies at the atomic level) and Relativistic Mechanics(which works better with larger objects) and are quite hard to unify.

Comment: Earlier (historical ) record where we can we see the way/basis  it was refuted ?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114341/  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89351/

Comment: The question might be about whether Newton's Law of Gravity is valid at atomic distances, rather than is it applicable to atomic systems.

Comment: Typically, you can find classical results in quantum mechanics  as relations between expectation values. Kepler's First is a little different. It might still apply. I asked a similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766494/quantum-analog-to-keplers-first-law/766591#766591

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's gravitation law has been tested at levels down to about a tenth of millimeter. It's a weak enough force that at atomic levels it is not been able to be measured at this point.

We've measured down pretty well to about a tenth of a millimeter, but much lower it becomes more difficult. They've tried down to a micron or so ($10^{-6}$ meters, 0.001 mm), with negative results pretty definitive to a few tenths of microns (ie, around 0.1 mm).

See some references below. No deviations have been found.

The main reason people have been trying to look for deviations is not to see how it compares with atomic or electrical forces, but whether is goes like $1/R^2$ or it varies from it, and if that could provide:
1) any reasons for some modification of the law of gravitation, at small but still larger than quantum scales (note that a quantum theory of gravity that has enough evidence to be acceptable still does not exist).
2) any indication that there might be more than the 3 dimensions to space. If there are variations in the inverse square law it could/would be evidence for  microscopic spatial extra dimensions around those sizes. Extra spatial dimensions are required for String Theory (and could be observable at the micron or smaller scales) or some other unproven physics quantum gravity theories.

There may be more recent results, I didn't find them in a quick search, but there's not been much of anything about any anomalies found at the small distances.

References:

1) Trying for sub micron: 2010: http://www.livescience.com/8789-gravity-small-scales-remains-mystery.html

2) Also around 100 to 1 micron: 2004: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C040802/papers/MOT004.PDF

3) Results down to 56 micron: 2007: plus results back to 1997: a ppt in a pdf, MB's (note, it also discusses the Pioneer anomaly, at solar system astronomical ranges, but I think that's been explained already):
http://moriond.in2p3.fr/J07/trans/wednesday/reynaud.pdf
From there: 'At 95% confidence, a
Yukawa interaction with
gravitational strength
must have a range
<56μm'

Comment: +1 Great consise answer Bob, I didn't know where you were intially going with measures of gravity, at that level, but I learned about a possible S. T. related test.

Comment: Thanks @CountTo10. I think the issue in small dimensions is how small are they. At Planck levels there will be strange and different things, but if we can find any evidence of anything at larger than Planck scales it'll give us some hints. Make your ST test count! (Even if more than 10 )

Answer (score 2):

Kepler's Second Law is one way of expressing the conservation of angular momentum of a system operating under a Central Force. That holds up in quantum In a straight forward way. By the Eherenfest Theorem and its many variations, not only is angular momentum conserved, there's even an analog to Newton's Second Law that applies to the relevant classical kinematic statements, e.g. $<dp/dt>=<-\nabla V>$. More generally, Any observable that commutes with the Hamiltonian is conserved.

Kepler's third law implies $<r^3>=c<\tau^2>$. A variation of the Ehrenfest Theorem applies here.

I'm not sure if Kepler I holds up though.

That would require $<1/r>=c_1+c_2<\cos{\theta}>+c_3<\sin \theta>$

Classically or otherwise $\cos{\theta}=\sin \theta =0$.

So we have only that $<1/r>=1/(a_0 n^2)$ with no reference to the angles.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of Kepler's first law in relativistic theory? The actual motion is not along ellipses, after all, and in case of strongly gravitating system it's dampened by gravitational wave emission, so I am not sure how to rescue it in general? It's just an approximation, unlike the angular momentum conservation for the quantum mechanical ground state, which is exact.

Comment: I would think so, with some modifications. From the orbit of Venus outward, Newtonian Gravity works about as well as General Relativity. Even under Newtonian gravity, the overall ellipse of a given' planet's orbit precesses over time due to perturbations from other planets. If you take Newton's formulation and further stipulate that gravitation effects propagate at a finite speed, you get that gravity is not only effected by mass, but by momentum of the gravitating body. This induces a perturbation that gives you effects similar to other planets in terms of precession.

Comment: That makes sense. If we are trying to compare apples to apples, then it becomes more, not less similar.