# Is it possible the quantum world to be actually deterministic after all?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, determinism

Possible the "Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle" (HUP) describes the fact that we are not able to probe beyond a small size scale into the quantum world because the relative long light waves just diffract over the particles giving a fuzzy sensor reading and measurements and when we finally try to probe these with shorter wavelength high energy photons the measurement totally disturbs the quantum state of these particles not giving us back their actual states and therefore making the measurements partially obsolete. Therefore, we can know the position of the particle at the instant of measurement but not also the momentum and vice versa. The HUP and measurement problem are ultimately entangled together.

However, maybe, if we could invent less intrusive or even better non-intrusive, indirect observation methods at high energies of probing and measuring then the HUP would be partially lifted or even nullified.

**My question's center theme is, hypothetically with the HUP gone, what will we then observe in the quantum system under observation? Will this then rendered and become classical?**

I personally believe that it is a matter of scale and for a hypothetical observer as small as these particles everything would look deterministic and obeying good classical physics and mechanics. Therefore the HUP should be not absolute for the quantum world but a relative apparent effect depending on the frame of reference and scale. This is just speculative but still an intriguing possibility beyond the SM of physics.

Maybe after all, nature is actually only deterministic and classical independent size scale and frame of reference and HUP is only an apparent effect due our macroscopic frame of reference relative to our quantum world and size scale? Maybe if a human observer could reduce his/her  size and frame of reference to the size of sub-atomic particles then he/she would observe a total classical reality of the quantum world where particles would appear like planets or stars obeying the classical laws of motion and classical mechanics?

Maybe HUP is not absolute but relative and does not apply for subatomic sized observers?

Does HUP quantitatively diminish with the observer or measurement tool size?

HUP is a property of elementary particles but not intrinsic to them but relative to the observer?

Therefore, the possibility of the quantum world to be actually classical and deterministic is still an open question.

What are your thoughts and analysis of the above hypothesis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the uncertainty principle a property of elementary particles or a result of our measurement tools?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114133/is-the-uncertainty-principle-a-property-of-elementary-particles-or-a-result-of-o)

Comment: Also, a nice [3b1b video](https://youtu.be/MBnnXbOM5S4) on this topic. TL;DR the uncertainty principle is not (only) about measuring.

Comment: Another thread with a related question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114133/is-the-uncertainty-principle-a-property-of-elementary-particles-or-a-result-of-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HUP can be derived directly from the axioms of quantum mechanics: it is not a property of our particular tools.

See Howard Percy Robertson. The uncertainty principle. *Physical Review*, 34(1):163, 1929 for a derivation from just definitions and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

[If you *could* violate the HUP, you would also use the measurement to make a perpetual motion machine](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2665), which seems a bit unlikely.