# Physiological Significance of Superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics, superposition, schroedingers-cat

To what extent is the concept of superposition appropriate to [physiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiology)? In other words, can organisms "actually" exist in a state of superposition?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228579/2451

Comment: Yes, Schrodinger's cat is a red herring.

Comment: Thank you for your help; however I'm not looking forward to informing her that she was correct!

Comment: Well, there are some biological mesoscopic systems in organisms, where quantum mechanisms are discussed. For example in antenna complexes in chloroplasts (where there is evidence for quantum coherent energy transport to the reaction centre). But whole organisms are too large and too noisy to keep up quantum coherence.

Comment: I'd say that in principle they do, but in practice they don't. This is because any physical system is a quantum system (as far as we know), but quantum effects usually play a role only at nanoscales and below. For example, a molecular gas at sufficiently high temperature and density (not so high, though) already behaves like a system of classical particles. The internal (rotational and vibrational) degrees of freedom still are subject to quantum laws (their energy are quantized and so on), but the gas as such is classical.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, an organism's physiology at a supra-molecular level obeys classical laws. This holds in general; specific phenomena may be explained in terms of and attributed to the quantum nature of reality. For sure, no superposition exists at a supra-molecular level.

Comment: I'm not sure what the sister has to do with the real question here. Perhaps remove that from the post.

Answer (score 3):

No they cannot. Any living system is an incredibly complicated, interacting quantum system. The countionous interaction (noise, heat bath, etc.) between particles makes it impossible for a coherent state to exist. However this is only true for the whole organism, on the level of single proteins, or other biomolecules quantum coherence may play an important role.

(Search for "quantum biology" for more. You might find some esoterics, but this is a perfectly legit and exciting area of physics.)

Answer (score 0):

Superposition stays until not observed. Organism as a whole can stay in such state (like both dead and alive Schrödinger's cat) until not observed, which has a negligible possibility in the physical world (physical-scales). In the quantum world (quantum-scales), it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers and comments have pointed out [decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) as a major obstacle for achieving superposition at macroscopic levels (which is absolutely correct, specially for the whole organism). However, this might be interesting: according to [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05929v1.pdf), Nature could have invented a way to maintain coherence for sufficiently long periods of time in biological systems such as the human brain. The key concept here is the *nuclear spin*, which is a quantum property related with the decoherence time: the lower the nuclear spin, the less the nucleus interacts with its sorroundings, then the less quickly it decoheres. In particular, the author proposes that the nuclear spins of something called Posner molecules (clusters of calcium and phosporous atoms), which [have been found](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12522821) in the human body, could remain entangled for long periods of time, serving as *neural* [*qubits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit), allowing the brain to store quantum information. All of this is summarized in the article's abstract:

> The possibility that quantum processing with nuclear spins might be operative in the brain is proposed and
>   then explored. Phosphorus is identified as the unique biological element with a nuclear spin that can serve as
>   a qubit for such putative quantum processing - a neural qubit - while the phosphate ion is the only possible
>   qubit-transporter. We identify the “Posner molecule”, Ca9(PO4)6, as the unique molecule that can protect the
>   neural qubits on very long times and thereby serve as a (working) quantum-memory. A central requirement for
>   quantum-processing is quantum entanglement. It is argued that the enzyme catalyzed chemical reaction which
>   breaks a pyrophosphate ion into two phosphate ions can quantum entangle pairs of qubits. Posner molecules,
>   formed by binding such phosphate pairs with extracellular calcium ions, will inherit the nuclear spin entanglement. [...] Multiple entangled Posner molecules, triggering non-local quantum correlations of neuron firing rates,
>   would provide the key mechanism for neural quantum processing. Implications, both in vitro and in vivo, are
>   briefly mentioned.

[Here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20161102-quantum-neuroscience/) is an excellent popular-level explanation of Fisher's proposal and investigation. I know little to nothing about the plausibility of such hypothesis, but you can judge by yourself.

Comment: It seems this answer is more appropriate for [another question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228579/21441) than this one.