# Uncertainty principle implies the non-deterministic universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, determinism

Does the uncertainty principle imply the non-deterministic universe, or just the fact that our model of the universe, the one based on observation, can be at most non-deterministic, since we will not be able to measure with perfect accuracy, even if such would exist (and therefore we will have to provide probability distributions rather than an event which should happen with overwhelming probability (term used by Terence Tao))?

Comment: You might be interested in [Bell's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isn't the uncertainty principle just non-fundamental limitations in our current technology that could be removed in a more advanced civilization?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/)

Comment: Thank you for clarificaiton, ACuriousMind. That answers my question.