# Why does heisenberg uncertainty principle work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Hiesenberg's Uncertainty Principle states that inaccuracy in momentum and position will always be there and we will never ever be able to get it 100% accurate. Suppose in future millions of years from now, we have equipments that can measure potential and kinetic energy of any object without having to measure it at two different point of time and at only one point of time then simply we can have the position and momentum at the same time of an object. The formula doesn't makes any sense so why and how does it work ?

Comment: *Hiesenberg's Uncertainty Principle states that inaccuracy in momentum and position will always be there and we will never ever be able to get it 100% accurate.* No it doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isn't the uncertainty principle just non-fundamental limitations in our current technology that could be removed in a more advanced civilization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/)