# Quantization as a functor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantization, category-theory

Can anyone give an mathematical elaboration of the following statement:

> *Quantization is a functor carrying the category of Hilbert space and linear maps to that of Symplectic manifolds satisfying some conditions specified by laws of Physics.*

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/6200 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/8606

Comment: where is that statement taken from?

Comment: That's not quantization. The direction is backwards.

Comment: See also [Geometric Quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization), and a article by [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/quantization.html)

Comment: See also [Bates and Weinstein](http://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/GofQ.pdf)

Comment: possible duplicate of (a superposition of) [Why quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46015/) and [What is quantization?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77030/). I think the answers by Urs Schreibers address this question quite well.

Comment: Quantization is ***not a functor***; second quantization is, trivially.