# Features used in quantum mechanics but not used in classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What are (and why?) all the variables (features) used in the models in quantum mechanics but not used in classical mechanics (e.g. spin, flavor)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46015/)

Comment: Thank you, ACuriousMind. The question you mentioned partially answers my question and is definitely relevant to my question.

Comment: do not agree the other question answers this question which is quite interesting/ independent in its own right. some further analysis/ research/ investigation of related areas see also chat, [toy models of QM](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20164/toy-models-of-qm)