# Why is commutation relations the first step in quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, commutator, quantization

Why is commutation relations the first step in quantization?

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75775/50583) to the older (and broader) "Why quantum mechanics?", since there the "natural" appearance of the commutation relations out of classical mechanics is discussed.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46015/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic although I agree, I think OP may be looking for a somewhat more basic answer.