# Deriving quantum mechanics from classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantization

why most quantum mechanics tools are derived from classical mechanics ?
(and everything is ok)

why we can do a safe jump from classical scalar quantities (Hamiltonian, momentum, angular momentum, spinning charge in a loop) to quantum operator quantities (Hamiltonian, spin.. ) using basic calculus.

a lot of confusing ideas are here, like :
the electron isn't really spinning but the derivation of the quantum magnetic moment by calculating the classical magnetic moment of a classical charge spinning in a circle leads to a true answer ..

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46015/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: Try the classic [Quantization is a mystery](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3116).