# Is an apple a quantum object? If we can only use apples to observe it

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider if you had a box, inside is an apple in a vacuum not affected by any gravitational fields. The position and momentum of the apple is unknown, you can only make observations of this apple by firing another apple into the box and using an apple detector that is a claw that can catch the apple you fired in.

Does the uncertainty principle apply to the apple in this system? If so then can you conclude that the uncertainty principle can never be proven to be a property of nature as opposed to a scale problem of measurement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will tennis ball produce same interference pattern in double slit experiment if everything was scaled up?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669910/) Apple, like a tennis ball, is a macroscopic object, which is why it may or may not behave in quantum way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Comment: That one doesn't really help, but this link discusses similar concepts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54184/

Can't hurt to leave this question open, as that thread above has mixed responses and is from 5 years ago.

Comment: This link also discusses the same big question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/

And another:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19500/