# Why doesn't QM violate causality? Has the definition of causality been stretched too far?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality

For example, if someone does the double slit experiment, their device will pick up a localized measurement. If they were to ask why the particle was measured at that specific location, there would be no answer (at least for the Copenhagen interpretation), meaning that there was no cause for the particle to be measured at that specific location.

Apparently this violates determinism but not causality, but to me there doesn't seem to be a cause for specific quantum events, so QM should violate both. All the physics definitions I have read about causality focus on causes not exceeding the speed of light, but don't address the causes in QM. Causality is then generalized to the point were it would be said that, in the first example, since the events that occur do not exceed the speed of light, then there is a continuous causal chain. While it doesn't violate the speed of light, there isn't a cause for the specific location of the measurement, so, to me at least, this violates causality.

EDIT: Changed collapse to measurement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does quantum mechanics break causality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230007/does-quantum-mechanics-break-causality)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133867/discussion-on-question-by-user289980-why-doesnt-qm-violate-causality-has-the-d).

Comment: seems there are physicists thinking about causality https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-mischief-rewrites-the-laws-of-cause-and-effect-20210311/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me, causality is defined as for every event there is a specific, direct cause for that event occurring.

This is not the definition which is used when we talk about superluminal signals and the like.  In physics, we typically use the word *causality* to describe the principle that (loosely speaking) effects cannot precede their causes. Your definition is indeed more closely related to what we would describe as determinism.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133868/discussion-on-answer-by-j-murray-why-doesnt-qm-violate-causality-has-the-defi).