# Does preventing/delaying a quantum jump in one part of an entangled system affect the other part?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

This question is related to the new experimental work related to catching and reversing a quantum jump in mid-flight. The relevant work can be found  [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00545).

Assume that we have two entangled quantum systems A and B of the same type as in the work above, "artificial superconducting atoms". Does a delay or reversal of a quantum jump for system A have any effect on its entangled partner system B? In other words, could a delay or reversal of a quantum jump related to system B be induced by suitable operations applied to its entangled twin, system A?

I suspect the answer is no, since such a possibility would make FTL information transfer possible,  but I am not sure. The experimental work and theoretical model (quantum trajectories ) are fairly complicated, and above my level at the moment, so at this point I cannot definitely answer this question . Is unitary evolution preserved in this context,  because it is known that unitarity would eliminate the possibility  of FTL information transfer (based on the density matrix formalism of quantum mechanics)? I would appreciate some clarification.

A related question (and other references in comments ) can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484282/31339)  or   [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484675/31339). Distinction must be made between continuous quantum jumps and  continuous collapse of the wavefunction,  so the latter will require a different experimental setup, and different quantum states.

Comment: found this https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108132 , but do not feel up to studying it.

Comment: About the quantum jump thing: knzhou just debunked the hype here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484675/109928. I proposed that page as a duplicate to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you @annav for your comment,  and the answer to my previous question.  In quantum simulation , the simulator is usually the simpler,  fundamental system, and the system to be simulated is the larger scale system (sometimes)  involving  emergent states. Drawing conclusions in the other direction (from the  larger system to the simpler one) is problematic, a lot depends on the specific mapping between the mathematical models  of the two systems, I agree with you.

Comment: As related to this question,  I think that for the large scale system (involving emergent states) it would be interesting  to see whether one can design experiments where nonunitary evolution must be taken into account.

Comment: Since nonunitary evolution is closely connected to nonlinear mathematical models, and since quantum mechanics is a linear theory,  it is then a necessity that one must consider large scale systems involving emergent states.

Comment: A few minutes ago I found this reference at physicsworld: https://physicsworld.com/a/to-catch-a-quantum-jump/ Please read the last paragraph of this article. That partially answers my question. Interesting, isn't it?