# If we can predict the quantum leap, won't that render quantum computers useless?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

Recent news from Yale... We can predict the quantum leap before the particle collapses its superposition. We can even change it to whichever position we like in real time.
In layman terms, as I understand with my limited knowledge, Schrodinger's cat can be SAVED.

But... Also to my limited knowledge, the core of how a quantum computer works is because of its superposition feature and its uncertainty.

Then put these two paragraphs together...
If the superposition is now old news, so would quantum computers.
Right?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Please read the excellent answer by @knzhou to this related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484675/does-the-new-finding-on-reversing-a-quantum-jump-mid-flight-rule-out-any-inter

Comment: Your question is mixing two things. The prediction of the quantum leap is THE experiment to show that a hidden parameter is no longer hidden. A quantum computer is based on the entanglement of polarization of thermic uninfluenced particles, for which we have to avoid any influence like in the Yale experiment. THE experiment is good for Nobel avard?