# Does the Minev experiment challenge the "many worlds" interpretation of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

[Minev's PhD thesis, "Catching and Reversing a Quantum Jump Mid-Flight"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484675/does-the-new-finding-on-reversing-a-quantum-jump-mid-flight-rule-out-any-inter) and the [Nature article that summarized it](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1287-z) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00545)) showed that one could monitor the quantum state of transitions that occurred across a connection between two microwave cavities at low temperature. The descriptions I've seen so far have argued that it challenges the Copenhagen interpretation because it show that the transitions occur over finite time. That's been asked and answered  (I never thought that was being claimed by anyone, but apparently I'm wrong. I was under the impression that the conjugate energy-time relationship and the Heisenberg Principle meant that the time for energy transitions needed to be non-zero.)

Contrariwise, I think the many-worlds interpretation is more directly challenged because it posits a split which gains independent existence.

So I suppose my questions are (1) whether people arguing about the fundamentals are paying attention to this set of experimental results and  (2) if there were a forum where we might view those discussions? The [one SE.physics discussion so far](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484675/does-the-new-finding-on-reversing-a-quantum-jump-mid-flight-rule-out-any-inter) focused on potential challenges to the supposed instantaneous nature of transitions.

Comment: I hope I fixed it. It's one of those shortened links at the t.co domain. If it disaapears you can find it at Minev's IBM pages.

Comment: The use of URL shortening services is strongly discouraged on Stack Exchange, and some shortened links are automatically blocked. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450/334566 Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/334566

Comment: I didn't use an URL shortening service. That was the url at the IBM website where the reference was located (as I indicated.) The Nature article was behind a paywall, and I hate making reference to paywalled locations when there are alternatives.  And I also provided a non-shortened URL to the phd thesis. (Apparently benrg found a different URL but it wasn't clear to me how this was identified.)