# Are quantum events such as decay, emission, absorption and tunneling truly instantaneous or is there some small time period?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, radiation, quantum-tunneling

Are quantum events such as decay, emission, absorption and tunneling truly instantaneous or is there some small time period?

Assuming there is an underlying cause for a quantum event it seems to me that we should expect some time interval between the cause and the effect even if the time intervals are too small to be experimentally measured.

Consider a magnet moving very gradually towards an iron filing. The iron filing is observed to start moving towards the magnet until it is drawn rapidly together with the magnet. The elapsed time of the event is the time between the iron filing beginning to move and being stationary with the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

The average delay before a decay or emission event is known as its "lifetime" (or, with a factor of $\ln 2$, its "half-life"). Quantum states with the same quantum numbers are indistinguishable. There is no difference between a system which happens to be on the cusp of a decay versus a system which happens to end up not decaying for many half-lives.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify that I am not asking about the lifetime. What I am getting at is the duration of an individual quantum event which would be expected to be constrained by the speed of light. Consider a magnet moving very gradually towards an iron filing. The iron filing is observed to start moving towards the magnet until it is drawn rapidly together with the magnet. The elapsed time of the event is the time between the iron filing beginning to move and being stationary with the magnet.

Comment: I knew you did not realize you were asking about the lifetime. (I’ve been there, too.) To get a result where transitions are constrained by the speed of light, you have to use a relativistic model like quantum field theory rather than the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation. The linked duplicate question has a number of excellent references in the comments. Indistinguishability in quantum mechanics is an observable phenomenon with thermodynamic consequences; the possibility of “hidden variables” is constrained from a number of different directions.

Comment: So using the QFT model would there be a time period for such quantum events? or using the the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation would there be a time period for such quantum events?

Comment: A relativistic theory should give you a result which respects relativity. There are two recent papers in [this possibly-related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/690277/44126) which would interest you, but I haven't read them yet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on one's perspective.

**We never start in an eigenstate**
If we are solving a Schrödinger equation for the eigenmodes, the solutions will already contain the particle on the two sides of the barrier or a photon simultaneously emitted and non-existent (with the atom in the excited state). Note that I am talking here not about superpositions, but about the eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian.

In practice we never start with an eigenstate, but with a superposition of them: as an electron localized on one side of a barrier or an atom in the excited state. We then observe the system evolve, and never return back to its original state _ either because the interaction with the environment causes decoherence at some point or because the time between the collapse and the revival is too long for actually observing the revival. We then talk about a *tunneling event* or an *emission/absorption event*, and we can attribute to them a characteristic time.

Mathematically we often treat such events in perturbation theory, e.g., considering an isolated excited atom and isolated EM field, and then turning on the perturbation and observing how the atom excitation "leaks" into the field. [Gamow's calculation of the radioactive decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamow_factor) is a classic here (which has been adopted to other situations, e.g., to [tunneling in quantum dots by Gurvitz](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.38.1747), and extensively used.)

**Beyond Quantum**
Note that there is nothings pecially *quantum* about this:

- same effects can be observed we discussing classical electromagnetic fields (i.e., the stationary and dynamic solutions of Maxwell equations).
- in thermodynamics/statistical physics we encounter extreme situations, where the system does not have time to explore all the states of the same energy and, contrary to our expectation, finds itself in one of these states for seemingly infinite time. This is what we refer to as *spontaneous symmetry breaking*. A required reading here is the Anderson's [*More is different*](https://cse-robotics.engr.tamu.edu/dshell/cs689/papers/anderson72more_is_different.pdf).

Comment: it is not clear from your comments as to your view on whether or not there is a time period for a quantum event such as atomic decay that one might expect to be constrained by c. Are you saying that there is a mathematical constraint? Consider  a scalable analogy of a magnet moving very gradually towards an iron filing.  The iron filing is observed to start moving towards the magnet until it is drawn rapidly together with the magnet. The elapsed time of the event is the time between the iron filing beginning to move and being stationary with the magnet.